# How to know whether an instance is scaled up or down in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

How to know whether a compute instance (it can be in a group of anything, clusters, MIG etc...) is scaled up or down in a given time period(lets say last month) programmatically?

Lets say that every instance in an managed instance group got an increase in VCPU by 2VCPUS, how to know this programmatically?

Comment: Scaling is horizontal (out), not vertical (up). MIGs will add/reduce instances, not make instances larger.

Comment: Okay but is this the case for k8 clusters or any other instance groups as well?

Comment: I cannot answer for Google Kubernetes. Containerized services have more options. Update your question as physical (VM) compute scaling is different that container scaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed Instance Groups are primarily designed for horizontal scaling.

You could use the [instanceGroupManagers().listManagedInstances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instanceGroupManagers/listManagedInstances) method to retrieve the list of instances in the MIG and use the [instanceGroupManagers.aggregatedList](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instanceGroupManagers/aggregatedList) to return the current state of instances.

However, you still need to periodically call the API and store the historical data yourself.